# how to generate schema and solr config while saving data from spark to solr

Tags: apache-spark, solr

I am new to solr. Please help me to get out of it. I want to save data from spark to solr, which i have done using SolrCloud mode through spark. but i want to define its schema file and solr config file for a particular core.

I do not want to use the DSE process. I have saved the data using following :

```
var writeToSolrOpts = Map("zkhost" -> zkhost, "collection" -> "sample")
in.write.format("solr").options(writeToSolrOpts).save
```

in which `sample` is collection name and `zkhost` is the port of zookeeper.

Comment: If you're using the schemaless mode, the schema is generated while you're indexing. If you don't want that to happen, you have to pre-define your schema and disable the update handler for the schemaless mode.

Comment: @MatsLindh Hi , thanks for your revert. i want to know is that possible to define schema by using spark ?? because i have seen that we can only save data to solrcloud mode where only collections exist . but i want to get a core and want to define schema and solrconfig by myself.

Comment: Which is what the default operation in Solr is - you define your schema and create your collection, then you tell Spark to index into that collection.

Comment: Hi @MatsLindh , thanks for your kind support . I successfully uploaded config file to zookeeper ,as it provides the "upconfig" option.But what i noticed is it also ask for other txt files like stopwords.txt and  etc. So i copied them as it is from _default config which solr provides and it worked.